# Trying to Load hrbrthemes Package, but Fail

Tags: r, r-package

I want to make some graphics to analyze Covid-19 with ggplot and hrbrthemes in R Google Colaboratory. But, when load the hrbrthemes package, I found the error like this

```
Error in library(hrbrthemes): there is no package called ‘hrbrthemes’
Traceback:

1. library(hrbrthemes)
```

Before I face this error, I have loaded ggplot2 and hrbrthemes package just like this

```
library(ggplot2)

library(hrbrthemes)
```

How I solved this? Can one of you help me to solve this problem? I'm very pleased when you can find the solution for me. Thank you ^^

Answer (score 3):

I had it three days ago, and today I found the solution.
you can try to install with

```
install.packages('https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/hrbrthemes/hrbrthemes_0.1.0.tar.gz', type='source', repos=NULL)
```

it works to me

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the "hrbrthemes" package yet? If not, you should install the package before loading it.

```
install.packages("hrbrthemes")
```

Answer (score 1):

You must first install `libcairo2-dev` before the `hrbrthemes` on Google Colab for R:

```r
system('sudo apt install libcairo2-dev')
install.packages('hrbrthemes')
library(hrbrthemes)
```

However, I haven't gotten it to be functional in Colab. Let me know if you get it to work!

Solution based on [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/hrbrthemes/issues/35#issuecomment-784544714).

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably haven't installed the package {hrbrthemes}.

You can install the package using the following command:

install.packages("hrbrthemes")

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest try install.packages("hrbrthemes") on console

Answer (score 0):

thank you for all your responses :) By the way, I had isntalled hrbrthemes package with install.packages() just like your recommend

install.packages('hrbrthemes')

But, I found the result like this after clicking the Run button about 3 until 4 times:

Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

also installing the dependency ‘gdtools’

Warning message in install.packages("hrbrthemes"):
“installation of package ‘gdtools’ had non-zero exit status”
Warning message in install.packages("hrbrthemes"):
“installation of package ‘hrbrthemes’ had non-zero exit status”

And then, when I run the library, the result is still like this

Error in library(hrbrthemes): there is no package called ‘hrbrthemes’
Traceback:

1. library(hrbrthemes)

Should I install the package with another way? Is the another way can influence to R packages that I had installed before?
By the way, before I installed the package, I had installed Python, R and R Studio in my laptop. My laptop has Windows 64 bit systems.